# Closed set in Baire space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I am reading a book on Banach spaces. It introduces the Baire space $\mathcal{N}=\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ as the product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology.

We have $\mathcal{N}$ is Polish.

In the proof of a result it uses the following: If we let $[\mathbb{N}]$ be the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then this is a closed subspace of  $\mathcal{N}$. Could anyone please explain why this is true?

Comment: Infinite subsets, or all subsets? It’s not true for the set of infinite subsets, but it is true for the set of all subsets of $\Bbb N$, provided that they’re identifying a set with its indicator function.

Comment: It says infinite subsets. A direct quote 'The space $[\mathbb{N}]$ is naturally identified as a closed subspace of the Baire space $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: That’s not the relevant quotation, though: what’s at issue is the definition of $[\Bbb N]$. Does it describe a topology on $[\Bbb N]$?

Comment: Nope,. It just says $[\mathbb{N}]$ is the set of all infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Fair enough; I suspect that Andreas has hit on what was intended.

Comment: Why is this tagged ([tag:banach-spaces])? I don't think that tag fits this question. (The question might be from a book on Banach spaces, but the space in question is not a Banach space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Naturally identified" leaves enough wiggle room to identify an infinite subset $X$ of $\mathbb N$ with the sequence in $\mathcal N$ that enumerates the elements of $X$ in increasing order.  The set of all these increasing sequnces is a closed subset of $\mathcal N$.

Comment: Glurp. Didn’t think of that; strikes me as rather a lot of wiggle room, but I can’t deny that it works. (+1)

Comment: Thank you Andreas, and Brian :)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but Baire Space came out in my studying and I've tried to prove that set of increasing sequences is closed, but I do not see it. Any help?

Comment: @Whoknows To show that the complement is open, consider any sequence $s$ in the complement, i.e., not increasing. Then there are $i<j\in\mathbb N$ such that $s_i\geq s_j$. The set of sequences that have the same $i$-th and $j$-th components as $s$ is open and is included in the complement of the set of increasing sequences.

Comment: But why is that set open? I mean, we know that the set of sequences that have the same first $n$ components as $s$ is an open set (basic, indeed), but that also holds with any finite number of components?  Why?

Comment: @Whoknows I don't understand your last comment. My previous comment showed that the complement, which I'll call $N$, of the set of increasing sequences includes (basic) open neighborhoods of each of its points. So $N$ is the union of those basic open sets and is therefore open itself.

Comment: What I mean is that I do not see why " The set of sequences that have the same i-th and j-th components as s is open".

Comment: @Whoknows The set in question is $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ where $X_i=\{s_i\}$, $X_j=\{s_j\}$, and $X_k=\mathbb N$ for all $k\neq i,j$. Here each of the factors $X_n$ is open in $\mathbb N$ (since this is a discrete space), and all but finitely many (namely $2$) of the factors are all of $\mathbb N$.  So the product is a basic open set, by definition of the product topology on $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$.